# Draw closed interval (line with strokes on both sides)

Tags: microsoft-visio

I need to draw an interval closed from both sides. It looks exactly like visio's timeline, except I don't need dates on it. When I configure timeline to hide the dates, small strokes on both sides disappear. Is there such a shape?